# Intent.ACTION_CALL don't make call on some devices when locked

Tags: android, android-intent, samsung-mobile

My post is more or less self describing in the title.

I am building an android app where the user can -by accepting an incoming alarm- to make a phone call to a specific number.
For that reason I use the method below:

```
private void doCall(String phoneNumber) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

It works pretty fine to most of the devices, even when the phone is locked with a pin, it makes the call.
The problem comes with the Samsung devices. When it is locked you first have to unlock to make the call, it doesn't matter if you use a lock pin or not.

Is this a special "security" thing from Samsung? Is there a workaround on this to make it work to every device?

Thanks!